# Adjustment in a regression for community level aggregation of individual level data

Tags: multiple-regression, interpretation, multilevel-analysis, causality

In a cross-sectional study based on geographical multilevel regression, the authors used both individual-level data AND features generated by aggregating the same individual data in the community and dichotomizing them based on being above or below the community median.

I am not sure about the interpretation of the coefficients for both the individual (IF in short) and community-level features (CF).
For the IF, are they the effect of such variables independently by the community being above/below the other communities for those variables?
For the CF features, would it be the effect of the community status not mediated by the individual status?

Is my interpretation correct? Is it a good or bad idea to put both IF and IF-generated CF together in a model?

Comment: Aside from the dichotomization (which I prefer to avoid usually), aggregating individual-level data into group features and then adding them to the adjustment set sounds a lot like a Mundlak machine, which is a good way to adjust for group-level confounding.

Comment: interesting! can you elaborate more?

Comment: The best resource I encountered is a [Richard McElreath's lecture](https://youtu.be/iwVqiiXYeC4?t=3297) where he gradually moves from fixed effects (varying intercepts for groups) to multilevel models (partial pooling across groups) to Mundlak machines. However, my interest is usually individual-level average treatment effects so I never bothered interpreting "IF-generated CF" (Mundlak features, I just use them for de-confounding) and can't help directly with your question. But I guess econometric literature might be helpful for interpreting these and I would start there.

Comment: Finally had the time to check the lecture. Is definitely the right anwser to the question!